# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - Angular - Unit Test Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Fixed!

```bash
node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/jest/bin/jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage --reporters=jest-junit --coverageReporters=cobertura --coverageReporters=html
```